# Twig complex array conversion

Tags: php, twig

How do I convert such logic into Twig 2.x?

```
<?php if (isset($pricerunner_category[$category['category_id']])) { echo $pricerunner_category[$category['category_id']]; } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible with the `attribute` function.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html

```
{% if attribute(pricerunner_category, category.category_id) is defined %}
    {{ attribute(pricerunner_category, category.category_id) }}
{% endif %}
```

Not sure if the `is defined` is necessary or not, added it based on the docs.